# Facebook ID change

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

im developing a web with Facebook Login. When the user login, i store the facebook id.

**The problem is that i change the AppID and AppSecret (because i create a new app in facebook) and the user id return by facebook is different than my old app**

Im using PHP v4.0 Facebook SDK and this is my code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => '***********',
          'secret' => '**********************',
          'cookie' => true,    
          'oauth'  => true,
        ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = null; 

    if ($user) {
        try {
            $me = $facebook->api('/me');
            $this->facebook_id = $me['id'];
```

Then i store it in a database..

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is intentionally.

Facebook does that for privacy reasons.

There is no way to obtain the same user id from different applications.

> The id of this person's user account. This ID is unique to each app and cannot be used across different apps.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user

Comment: Just to add. If you have several apps you can use the Business Mapping API to check what is the user id is your different apps for the current user. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

Comment: Thank both for the clarification. I thought it was so but wanted to double check before moving into production.